# crash - thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed (@unowned CMTime),add the code(guard let self = self else{return}) in block,but it doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, crash, avplayer

My users are facing this crash that got reported inside Firebase Crashlytics. I can see the Class and Method where the crash took place but couldn't figure out the reason for the crash. Everything works fine inside simulator and on the real device that I have.

```
guard let self = self else{return}
```

add that code but it doesn't work.I need some help figuring out the actual cause of this crash. Here is the crash log.

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  FPMeditation                   0x16c234 closure #1 in PlayerManager.addPlayObserver() + 4376789556 (AudioPlayer.swift:4376789556)
1  FPMeditation                   0x166f74 thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed (@unowned CMTime) -> () + 4376768372 (<compiler-generated>:4376768372)
2  AVFCore                        0xc46c -[AVPeriodicTimebaseObserver _fireBlockForTime:] + 68
3  AVFCore                        0xc3ac -[AVPeriodicTimebaseObserver _handleTimeDiscontinuity] + 168
4  AVFCore                        0xbf2c __AVTimebaseObserver_timebaseNotificationCallback_block_invoke + 116
5  libdispatch.dylib              0x2914 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
6  libdispatch.dylib              0x4660 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
7  libdispatch.dylib              0x12b60 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 944
8  CoreFoundation                 0x51cd4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 16
9  CoreFoundation                 0xbeac __CFRunLoopRun + 2540
10 CoreFoundation                 0x1f3b8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600
11 GraphicsServices               0x138c GSEventRunModal + 164
12 UIKitCore                      0x5196a8 -[UIApplication _run] + 1100
13 UIKitCore                      0x2987f4 UIApplicationMain + 2092
14 libswiftUIKit.dylib            0x31184 UIApplicationMain(_:_:_:_:) + 104
15 FPMeditation                   0x3491c main + 4375513372 (ReminderTableViewCell.swift:4375513372)
16 ???                            0x103281a24 (缺少)
```

And the actual code.

```
private func addPlayObserver() {
//播放状态监听
        avPlayer.currentItem?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "status", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.new, context: nil)
        //缓冲状态监听
        avPlayer.currentItem?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "loadedTimeRanges", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.new, context: nil)

        avPlayer.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "loadedTimeRanges", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.new, context: nil)
        AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "isOtherAudioPlaying", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.new, context: nil)
        
        //播放结束事件监听
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(onItemDidPlayToEndTime), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: self.avPlayer.currentItem)
        //播放失败监听
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(onItemFailedToPlayToEndTime), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemFailedToPlayToEndTime, object: self.avPlayer.currentItem)
        
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(onItemPlaybackStalled), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemPlaybackStalled, object: self.avPlayer.currentItem)
        //监听普通被打断事件比如电话和闹钟
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(interruptionNotification), name: AVAudioSession.interruptionNotification, object: nil)
        
        //是否开始播放
        var isStartPlay = false
        //设置定时监听，更新播放进度
        timeObserver = avPlayer.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: CMTime.init(value: 1, timescale: 1), queue: DispatchQueue.main, using: {[weak self] (time) in
            guard let self = self else{return}
            //加载完成开始播放
            //添加前置判断条件“self?.playStatus != .prepare”的原因：
            //有时候，可能先播放了，ready事件稍后才回来.比如：
            //1. play的同时，调用了seekto
            //2. 本地音乐也是
            if isStartPlay == false, time.value > 0, self.playStatus != .prepare {
                isStartPlay = true
                self.playStatus = .play
            }
            
            //开始播放才
            if time.value > 0{
                //计算播放进度
                self.playProgress = self.calculatePlayProgress()
            }
           
            //播放进度
            if (self.playStatus == .play) {//状态过滤，避免ready事件还没回来，duration为0
                let progress = time.seconds / CMTimeGetSeconds((self.avPlayer.currentItem!.duration))
                self.currentProgress = progress
                //进度到20%时是否打统计
                if progress == 0.2 && self.isStatisticWhenTwenteen == true {
                    self.isStatisticWhenTwenteen = false
                    self.handleStatisticPlayProgress()
                }
                //设置实际播放时间
                PlayerFinishManager.shared.setupRealPlayRealTotalTime(seconds: Int(self.avPlayer.currentItem!.duration.seconds))
            }
        })
}
```

Comment: I see a few `self.avPlayer.currentItem!`, what if `currentItem` is nil? It will cash here... Also, do you have a method `addPlayObserver`? Is that this one?

Comment: Hello,thank you for your reply,the method code has been completed.

Comment: Maybe this line `let progress = time.seconds / CMTimeGetSeconds((self.avPlayer.currentItem!.duration))` ends in a division by 0.

Comment: it's possible,let me change it and try.Thank you.